# How I start the service openOffice in Windows 7, I have this line command but I don't have idea how to use this

Tags: java, service, openoffice.org

This is the line command:

```
soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard
```

Comment: Perhaps try without -nofirststartwizard

Comment: Did you execute this while in the OpenOffice program directory? Is there a program named "soffice", or is it "soffice.exe"?

Comment: It looks like this command is from the [JODConverter documentation](http://www.artofsolving.com/node/10.html).

Answer (score 0):

To start OpenOffice in listening mode, create a `.bat` file like this:

```
c:
chdir "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\OpenOffice 4\program\"
start soffice -headless -accept=socket,host=0,port=2002;urp;
```

If it does not work, then check that the paths are correct.  Run the commands at a command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, `cmd.exe`) to see if there are any errors.

See also https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Starting_OpenOffice.org_in_Listening_Mode.